# How to change Focused TreeNode Back Color in Treeview

Tags: c#, windows, treeview

I have a Treeview control in C# Windows Application.

Attached the screenshot of the current TreeNode.

[image]

Content is little bit Blacked out.

Searched Internet but could not find the right solution. How can I change the BackColor of this Node to DarkGray?

Comment: When I google for it, I am getting results for change of color of `SelectedNode` instead of this `Focused` Node. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hello, Anyone there to give me hints atleast...